# Doctrine Batch Processing doesn't clear memory?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, batch-processing

I am trying to use [a technique suggested by Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html#mass-object-processing) to process a large number of objects. The technique suggests that by using an iterator and by detaching after processing each iteration, memory usage should be kept to a minimum (they speak about an increase of a few KB for processing 10000 records).

However, when I try to do this, I do not see any objects freed. In fact, I am retrieving a little more than 2000 assets and this increases my memory usage by 90 MB. Clearly, these objects are not freed. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? My code looks as follows:

```
$profiles = //array of Profile entities 
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->addSelect('file')
            ->leftJoin($profileNodeEntityName, 'pn', JOIN::WITH, 'pn.icon = a OR pn.asset = a')
            ->leftJoin(
                $profileEntityName,
                'p',
                JOIN::WITH,
                'pn.profile = p OR p.logo = a OR p.background = a OR p.pricelistAsset = a OR p.pdfTplBlancAsset = a OR p.pdfTplFrontAsset = a OR p.pdfTplBackAsset = a'
            )
            ->innerJoin('a.currentFile', 'file')
            ->where('p IN (:profiles)')
            ->setParameter('profiles', $profiles)
            ->distinct(true);

        $iterableResult = $qb->getQuery()->iterate();

        $start = memory_get_usage() / 1024;
        while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
            // process $row[0]
            $this->getEntityManager()->detach($row[0]);
        }
        $end = memory_get_usage() / 1024 - $start;
        // $end is more of less equal to 90000 or 90 MB
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should also detach the related entities, or set cascade={"detach"} on the associations.

Comment: Yes, it should. I used the same technique for serializing more than a million entities to XML while not using more that 60 megs of memory.

Comment: And one more thing: the doctrine manual tells that iterate() method does not work with result sets with joined entities.
'Iterating results is not possible with queries that fetch-join a collection-valued association. The nature of such SQL result sets is not suitable for incremental hydration.'